# VTK file formats - THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, visualization, vtk

This is my very first post at Stack Overflow, although I have been using it for years now.

For my thesis project, I have to develop GUI for Digital Wind Tunnel on web. As an additional points for mark, 3D presentation of results would be awesome. I have started with many remote visualization techniques but have always came down to some particular JavaScript library, Three.JS. I have already managed to create simple examples and load STL files. 
However next step was loading VTK files as those can get output with OpenFOAM.
As we all know, VTK file formats can contain a lot of different data, not only colors and geometry. Therefore I have tried to first visualize simple VTK file with only points, polydata and rgb color, however I have failed miserably. I am successful with obtaining geometry but it seems that colors do not get read from VTK file.
I have followed [VTKloader #7602](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/7602) but I am either unlucky or knowledge I posses it not sufficient.

[Hexagonial surface, geometry has no color attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwNKz.png)

```
var loader = new THREE.VTKLoader();
            loader.load( "models/vtk/p_colors_faceNUM.vtk", function ( geometry,material ) {

                geometry.center();
                geometry.computeVertexNormals();

                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

                console.log(mesh);
                mesh.side = THREE.DoubleSide;

                console.log(geometry);
                mesh.position.set( - 0.075, 0.005, 0 );
                mesh.scale.multiplyScalar( 0.2 );
                scene.add( mesh );

            } );
```

Comment: Hi, I am working on the same issue. Perhaps did you manage to visualize vtk format with the colors?
Thank you!